# An error occurred in an after hook ChildProcess::LaunchError: (216)

Tags: ruby, rspec, watir-webdriver, child-process

I am trying to run a test using watir-webdriver and rspec in IE9 on Virtualbox.  When I run the test I get the following error:

```
An error occurred in an after hook ChildProcess:LaunchError: (216) 
occurred at F:/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/childprocess-0.5.5/lib/childprocess/windows/process_builder.rb:87in 'create_process'
```

Rspec returns:

```
Failure/Error: let(:x) {@browser ||=Watir::Browser.new :ie} 
ChildProcess::LaunchError: (216)
G:/Test.rb:12:in 'new'
G:/Test.rb:12:in 'block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
G:/Test.rb:13:in 'block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I am able to run the same test on my native version of IE10, Chrome, and Firefox.

Everything that I have searched about the error relates to:

```
216 - The image file %1 is valid, but is for a machine type other than the current machine. - ERROR_EXE_MACHINE_TYPE_MISMATCH
```

Comment: which windows version is running on that vm?  (helps if trying to duplicate)

Comment: The VM is running windows 7

Comment: What ruby are you running on?  (ruby -v)